# Display of threads in VS 10

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio

I am trying to view the threads on the "threads" window but nothing appears there even when I use only one thread at the run-time. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when application is halted threads are displayed. Have you halted application on breakpoint?